# _.sortBy object key value for d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js

I know you're not supposed to sort javascript objects but I need to for a d3 chart. I have an object with a key of FICO score ranges and value of the count of how many in that range

```
var counts = {680-700: 30, 620-640: 41, 640-660: 24, 660-680: 10}
```

I need to return a sorted object such that the lowest value keys come first.

```
var desired_obj = { 620-640: 41, 640-660: 24, 660-680: 10, 680-700: 30  }
```

I attempted to use _.sortBy but it only returns the values

```
 _.sortBy(counts, function(val, key) { return val })
```

Comment: Post your chart-making code: where do you need a sorted dictionary? A JavaScript object has no order, so sorting it makes no sense.

Comment: Is there a reason `counts` can't be an array? e.g. `[{range: '680-700', count: 30}, {range: '620-640', count: 41}, {range: '640-660', count: 24}, {range: '660-680', count: 10}]`

Comment: @shawnb no, that would be fine

Comment: @shawnb got it. thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used `var map = _.map(counts, function(val, key) { return {label: key, value: val } )` and then sorted `_.sortBy(map, function(x) { return x.label.split("-")[0] })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, JavaScript objects **explicity have no order** in the keys. (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/1007263)

If you need to ensure order, you must convert your object into an array.
You can do that easily with underscore:

```
a = {a:1, b:3, c:2}
_.map(a, function(value, key) { return {key: key, value: value} })
// [{"key":"a","value":1},{"key":"b","value":3},{"key":"c","value":2}]
```

And you can use chain to sort after mapping:

```
_.chain(a).map(function(value, key) { return {key: key, value: value} }).sortBy('value').value()
//"[{"key":"a","value":1},{"key":"c","value":2},{"key":"b","value":3}]"
```